# function which will return all the fields from google play

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a function which will return all the fields from google play.That is if we pass com.xyz.abcdef to the function, the function should return, a named value collection of fields such as appname,description, screenshotUrls[], category, rating etc from Google play.
Is it possible to do the task in php.Is there any controller or function in php to do this task.Can anyone help me.

Thanks.